# How do I remove the quotation marks from a .csv file?

Tags: c#, list, file, replace

I read in a .csv file.

The contents of which looks like this:

> 1;"final60";"United Kingdom";"2013-12-06 15:48:16";
>
> 2;"donnyr8";"Netherlands";"2013-12-06 15:54:32"; etc

At the moment I am just trying to remove the quotation marks from each line using the `Replace` method. This is what I have attempted which doesn't appear to do anything. Although doesn't seem to break the program in anyway.

```
try
{
    string item2;
    List<string> list = File.ReadLines("file.csv").ToList();
    foreach (string listLine in list)
    {
         Console.Write("#  ");
         // seperate up this line into a new list by ; 
         List<string> listItems = listLine.Split(';').ToList();
         foreach(String item in listItems)
         {
              if (item == "&quot;")
              {
                    item2 = item.Replace("&quot;", "");
              }
              else
              {
                    item2 = item;
              }
              Console.Write(item2);
         }
         Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Let the user know what went wrong.
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

How can I remove the quotation marks in each line?

Comment: Your looking for the 7 character *string* `&quot;` is that what's actually in the file? Its an HTML entity and has no meaning in C#  use `"\""` to replace a basic double-quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be with Regex, consider this pattern:

```
\"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hsXTTBkHBIcHxvZn)

It will match all `"` in the string so you could do something like this:

```
var s = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
```

Here `input` would be the entire file or even just one line, the pattern would be `\"`, and `s` would be the resulting `string` after the removal of those double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

It is much easier to use some existing CSVParser instead of doing this manually. 
You could use for example:

- [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)
- [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)

Parsing CSV files manually introduces a lot of potential risks. Even if you solve your above challenge you cannot be sure that there won't be other cases when your CSV file will not be parsed appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I am however very new to C# and trying to get a hold of the basics for now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not working lies here:

```
List<string> listItems = listLine.Split(';').ToList();
foreach(String item in listItems)
{
    if (item == "&quot;") {
        item2 = item.Replace("&quot;", "");
    }
}
```

Think about what kind of data `item` is going to hold, because it seems like you are checking to see if a `char` is equal to `&quot`, which is the correct thing to do, but maybe `item` isn't a char? Think about what `List<string> listItems = listLine.Split(';').ToList();` and `foreach(String item in listItems` are doing :)

Comment: I assumed `listItems` would be a string (which obviously is an array of characters). So I used the `foreach` loop to iterate through each character in the string to check if anyone of them was a quotation mark!?

Comment: That is what you want to do, yes. But you are not iterating through each character in each string, you are looping through each string inside listItems. You'd want to see each character by itself, and right now you are comparing a whole string to a single character.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with a 3rd party library that output this format.  A tricky part happen when a field embeds the quote character.  To avoid this, the following code makes sure that the field separator is adjacent to it (or begin/end of line).  This implementation will if the field separator is embedded at beginning or end of a field.

```
        private void FileStripDoubleQuotedFields(string csvPath, string fieldSeparator)
        {
            // Input file:  "asdf"   "bfdsa" "fdsa"
            // Output file:  asdf   bfdsa   fdsa

            string stripped = csvPath.Replace(".", "_stripped.");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvPath))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stripped, true, reader.CurrentEncoding))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string newLine = line
                        .RegexReplace("^\"", "")        // begin of line
                        .RegexReplace("\"" + fieldSeparator + "\"", fieldSeparator) // between fields
                        .RegexReplace("\"" + fieldSeparator, fieldSeparator) // field followed by empty field(s)
                        .RegexReplace(fieldSeparator + "\"", fieldSeparator) // empty field(s) followed by field
                        .RegexReplace("\"$", "");       // ending quote

                    writer.WriteLine(newLine);
                }
            }
            string orgPath = csvPath.Replace(".", "_spire.");

            File.Move(csvPath, orgPath);
            File.Move(stripped, csvPath);

            File.Delete(orgPath); // breakpoint here to compare before the delete
        }

    public static string RegexReplace(
        this string input,
        string pattern,
        string replacement,
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, options);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I got a bug when the csvPath contained a dot so I used string stripped = Path.GetDirectoryName(csvPath) + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(csvPath) + "_stripped.csv"

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach(String item in listItems)
 {
     if (item == "\"")
     {
          item2 = item.Replace("\"", "");
     }
     else
     {
          item2 = item;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, although not entirely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the `"` quotation mark? `item.Replace("&quot;", "");` isn't doing anything because there is no occurence of the substring `&quot;`.

Replace

```
if (item == "&quot;")
{
    item2 = item.Replace("&quot;", "");
}
    else
{
    item2 = item;
                                    }
```

with `item.Replace("\"", "")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for and replacing the chr code instead of the escape sequence.

I believe you'd want chr(34)

Answer (score 0):

How about some LINQ?

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("file.csv")
                .Select(line => string.Join("", line.Select(c => c != '"')));
```